# Poisson process question call centre

Tags: probability, poisson-process

A call centre gets an average of 5 calls per minute. Assuming the number of calls received can be modelled by a poisson process, find probability that call centre will receive

i) more than two calls in one minute

ii) will receive 20 calls in 5 minutes

Attempt

i)  Using, $\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!}$, where $\lambda$ is the mean. The probability of less than or equal to two calls in one minute $P(\le 2)$ = P(0) +P(1) +P(2)  = $\frac{e^{-5}5^{0}}{0!} $ + $\frac{e^{-5}5^{1}}{1!} $ + $\frac{e^{-5}5^{2}}{2!} $. Therefore the probability of more than two calls = $1 - P(\le 2)$  ? I am not sure if this is correct?

ii) In this case, $\lambda = 5\times5 = 25$. So $P(k = 20) = \frac{e^{-25}25^{20}}{20!}$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: That looks about right to me